# python create variable from first x letters in each line of a text file

Tags: python

New to scripting

Have 2 txt files with output of show vlan brief from cisco switches. Looking to compare the two and determine any differences. Below is a script that shows the lines that are equal, but for some reason if i change the '==' to '!=' it will print out the result 19 times. Hoping someone could point me to the right direction. Rather than getting it right, i'd like to understand the logic behind why it is doing this. Thanks in advance.

TEXT FILE EXAMPLE:

```
n1000v# show vlan brief
 VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
 ---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
 1    default                          active    Po1, Po2, Po12, Veth1, Veth2
                                                 Veth3, Veth10, Veth100
 2    VLAN0002                         active
 100  VLAN0100                         active
```

-I'd like to only return the following if there is a difference

```
1 default
2 VLAN0100
100 VLAN0100
```

Code example:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
file3 = open("results.txt", "w")
list1 = file1.readlines()
list2 = file2.readlines()
file3.write("here: \n")
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if  i==j:
            file3.write(j)
file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
```

Comment: Nevermind this part:

-I'd like to only return the following if there is a difference

1 default
2 VLAN0100
100 VLAN0100

Comment: Hi and welcome. You should edit the question rather than adding changes as comments.

Comment: Added an answer on the actual question, i.e. why this happens. Regarding how to do go about this, I would consider using regular unix tools for this. E.g. piping together `grep` to filter the lines you're interested in and `awk`ing to choose the interesting columns and then `diff`ing the results. Or, if you want to do this in Python, you could look at the [difflib module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could simply read each file simultaneously line by line, and then print (or write to another file) whenever two lines do not match up. The following code also prints the line numbers, which I thought to be a useful addition.

```
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('test2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    print("line\tfile1\tfile2\n")
    for i, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(file1, file2), 1):
        if line1 != line2:
            print("{}:\t\t{}\t{}".format(i, line1.strip(), line2.strip()))
```

Output for my test files:

```
line    file1   file2

1:      that    this
6:      5       6
7:      bird    tree
```

**The understanding the logic part:** well, you are looping one file line-by-line per line in the other file (nested loop), so changing the equality (true at most once) to an inequality (true in all other cases) will result in the line being printed for all those cases, which apparently is 19 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "I'd like to understand the logic behind why it is doing this". Consider this simplified version:

```
list1 = ["line1", "line2", "line3"] 
list2 = ["line1"] 
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i != j:
            print j
```

This will print out `line1` exactly 2 times, since that's how often it doesn't appear in list1.